# Regex - Split string into array based on punctuation/spaces

Tags: php, regex

I need a way to split a string into several different parts based on the presence of punctuation marks or spaces.

What I mean by this, is that every word should be split into its own array element, furthermore punctuation *which is at the start or at the end* of the word should also be put into its own array element.

E.g:
I need to be able to turn the string `Hello, Harry Potter. I'm Tom Riddle.` into

```
array(
   "Hello",
    ", "
    "Harry",
    "Potter"
    ". ",
    "I'm",
    "Tom",
    "Riddle",
    ". "
)
```

So punctuation in the middle of words (e.g. apostrophes in the middle of words) should not cause a separation
**Edit: ** so to clarify the desired behaviour, `I'm`, `didn't`, etc. should remain one word, but `hello!`, `"okay,` etc should be separated from the punctuation mark at the start or end.

Also, the punctuation marks which I want to be included in the search are:

- . (full stop/period)
- ? (question mark)
- ! (exclaimation mark)
- , (comma)
- ; (semi-colon)
- : (colon)
- (-) (hyphen-dash)
- ( (start bracket)
- ) (end bracket)
- { (start squigly brace)
- } (end squigly brace)
- [ (start square bracket)
- ] (end square bracket)
- ' (single quotation mark)
- " (double quotation mark)
- … (elpises)

The closest I have found to the result I need is this:

```
preg_split('/(\s|[\.,\/])/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

However, the problems with this are:

- Punctuation mid-word counts as normal punctuation
- The array element containing the array element does not contain the space as well. **Edit:** Sorry for the vagueness; by this, I meant that I wanted the punctuation characters to contain the space which is after/before the puntuation mark. e.g. If it is a comma, it would be `,` (space after), but if it is an opening bracket, it would be `(` (space before).
- When I add the rest of the punctuation marks I need (`preg_split("/(\s|[\.?!,;:-(){}[]'\"…\/])/",`) I get an error. I'm pretty sure that this error is due to an unescaped character, so I ran that whole thing through `preg_quote`, which returned `\.\?\!,;\:\-\(\)\{\}\[\]'"…`, but this still gives the error: `Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '…' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in [...][...] on line 5`

My understanding of regex is fairly limited, but after looking at the php docs I can gather that the code above separates words at each whitespace it encounters, or every time it encounters a comma or a punctuation. (Correct me if I'm wrong there?) And as I understood, adding the rest of the characters within the square brackets would make it separate the string at any of those characters as well(?) Since this isn't working, I suppose I have some sort of fundamental misunderstanding about how this works, so an explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really want *all* word-internal punctuation to stay attached? Also it looks like you want to tokenize each punctuation character separately (but attach nearby whitespace), which is most of the work. If you really do, this should do it. Comes with a test string to show it at work.

```
$string = "Hello, it's me-me-it's-me!!! o... (a friend?)";
print_r( preg_split("/(\w\S+\w)|(\w+)|(\s*\.{3}\s*)|(\s*[^\w\s]\s*)|\s+/", $string, 
        -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE) );
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => ,
    [2] => it's
    [3] => me-me-it's-me
    [4] => !
    [5] => !
    [6] => !
    [7] => o
    [8] => ... 
    [9] => (
    [10] => a
    [11] => friend
    [12] => ?
    [13] => )
)
```

This is how it works:

1. `(\w\S+\w)`  Capture any word of 3+ characters, allowing embedded non-letters.
2. `(\w+)` Capture any word (to catch short words).
3. `(\s*\.{3}\s*)` Capture ellipsis `...`, together with any surrounding space.
4. `(\s*[^\w\s]\s*)` Capture any non-letter, non-space characters individually; but attach any nearby spaces.
5. `\s+`   Any other spaces (i.e., between words) split the string, but are *not* captured.

If you want to be selective about what can be inside a word, replace the `\S+` in the first alternative with a list of what you want to allow, e.g., `[\w'-]+` to allow apostrophes and hyphens only.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response; what you describe in number 4 does not appear to be working, or perhaps you misunderstood my question (apologies if it is poorly worded). https://gyazo.com/2db04904b5f9a5c9d06a7986c507b057 What my intended result was was for there to be a space after the comma, so 2 would be `", "`. If that isn't possible, then is it possible to make spaces also return in the array so that I can loop through it and manipulate it like that?

Comment: Actually ignore that last comment, looking at my code, I think it would be easier to just have the spaces there as their own elements (so there would be an array element which contains only a single space). Is it possible to alter the code to do that?

Comment: Oops, if I'd used `var_dump()` too I would have caught the error. Indeed that was supposed to capture the space with the comma, not sure yet what I did wrong. But I was hoping you'd see how this approach works and be able to tweak it to whatever you actually want (which is still not totally clear, though this aspect of your -- original-- requirements was).

Comment: Sure it's possible to change the requirements. But be aware that SO folks (and all programmers) get a little annoyed when you do that. Next time you can't avoid asking "solve my messy problem" questions, make every effort to understand and specify _exactly_ what it is you need from the start. So now do you want _all_ spaces to be returned as individual tokens or do you still want spaces between words to be discrarded (which is a crazy way to tokenize)?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; the SO app signed out so I didn't get a notification >.<  And yeah, sorry, I know how annoying that is, I'll just stick to the original question, which your answer solves well enough, so I'll just mark it accepted. As for understanding how it works, I think I understand everything apart from how the space is attached in no. 4; do you think you can explain that please?

Comment: Part 4 should have ended in `\s*` -- that was a cut-and-paste error. So the middle part (the character class `[^\w\s]`) selects *one* character that's not a word or space character, and the `\s*` on the sides adds any adjacent spaces (if they hadn't been read already by another part of the regexp.)

Answer (score 4):

This will do it, however the output is slightly different as you included `'` as a character to split on, so `I'm` will be split:

```
$result = preg_split('/(\.\.\.\s?|[-.?!,;:(){}\[\]\'"]\s?)|\s/',
                     $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

It might be simplified, but I just included the ellipses `...` with an optional space OR all your other characters with an optional space OR a space.

You need to escape the dots `.` outside of the character class `[]`, escape the `[` and `]` inside the character class and `-` needs to be escaped or come first or last so as not to denote a range. Obviously you need to escape the quote that you use to contain the pattern, in this case the single `'`.

You didn't specify whether a space is required on either side of the punctuation and it isn't clear if this *"Punctuation mid-word counts as normal punctuation"* means it should or shouldn't count.

Comment: Haha was about to ask a question but I see that you edited it in :P Thank you very much, this works well  :) May I just ask why there isn't a way to exclude results which fall in between characters A-Z? When I was trying to solve this myself, I thought that I could perhaps use the `^` to exclude such instances, but I couldn't find a way to do it. Did I misunderstand how negation works?

Comment: Edited last paragraph.

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness; I updated the question to clarify the desired behaviour.

Comment: Hmmm... I see.  Still vague, what if `(` or `"` is the first character in the string with no space before it?

Comment: I was originally planning to have those not have a space (it was just so that it would be easier to recreate the string from the array), but now that I think about it, I think it would be better to keep the punctuation without any spaces, and to keep the spaces in between them (so there would be an array element of just a space (` `,) ), Is that possible? Should I edit the question to say that instead?

Comment: oh umm also, the first code you gave (`/(\.\.\.\s|[-.?!,;:(){}\[\]\'"]\s?)/'`) worked, but this new one doesn't work with punctuation at the start/end of a string:  https://gyazo.com/f58e00605becc46d94292449abd1e34a

Comment: Thanks for your help; another answer was able to stop words being broken with punctuation in the middle, so I marked that as accepted, but here's an upvote for your explanation; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In general you could use the pattern

```
word character+[all your punctuation characters here]+word character(*SKIP)(*FAIL)
```

For example:

```
\w[\[\].?\"\']\w(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[\[\].?\"\']
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Jc5z6e/1).